# React createRef not working with Redux. childRef.current always returns null

Tags: reactjs, redux, null, ref, create-ref

After a lot of googling, I can't find a solution. I need to call a child function from the parent component. Both are class components.

Some code

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.childRef = React.createRef();
      this.setAbilities();
    }
```

Rendering child component

```
{this.props.enemyChamp.abilities.map(ab => (
                            <AbilityButton
                            ref={this.childRef}
                            onCast={(caster, ability)=>this.castAbility(caster, ability)}                               
                            index={this.abilities[ab].id}
                            />
                        ))}
```

Function I want to call in `AbilityButton.js`

```
    castEnemyAbility = (ability, abIndex) => {
    var caster = "enemy";
    if(this.props.onCast(caster, ability)) {
        this.startCooldown(abIndex);
        this.cdTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            
        }, this.getAb().coolDown)
    }
}
```

exporting parent component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
setAbilities,
doDamage, heal,
regenMana, regenHealth
```

}, null, {forwardRef: true})(Fight);

I tried with and without `{forwardRef: true}`, Tried with an alternative method of rendering the Child component:

```
 <AbilityButton
                            wrappedComponentRef={ref => this.childRef = ref}
                            onCast={(caster, ability)=>this.castAbility(caster, ability)}                               
                            index={this.abilities[ab].id}
                            />
```

I tried so many combinations, and after lots of trial and error and a lot of googling, I decided to ask for help.

`this.childRef.current` always returns `null`. Any advice? I'm tired of trying

Comment: `AbilityButton` , is it mounted on the DOM? Are you doing any conditional rendering?

Comment: @Shan found another method to fix my problem.